# How to get more than 512 chars from the server using SignalR?

Tags: javascript, signalr, maxlength

I would like to use SignalR to get some dynamic data from the server when a certain event is triggered on the client side.

This is my JavaScript-Code:

```
window.myHub.server.myFunction(id).done(function (data) {
    $.each(data, function () {
        console.log(this.Property);
    });
});
```

And my code on the side of the server:

```
public MyClass MyFunction(Guid id)
{
    MyClass data = _repository.GetById(id);
    return data;
}
```

Unfortunately, the response only contains the first 512 chars, everything else is truncated. Can I change this limit?

Comment: what version are you using ?

Comment: I'm using version 2.0.1.

Comment: I'm using 2.0.3 and tested sending 1024 chars without any problem, try checking http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/performance-and-scaling/signalr-performance#tuning

Also this https://github.com/SignalR/SignalR/issues/1205

Comment: If you call `string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);` inside of `MyFunction` is the `json` string truncated? Also how is `MyFunction` getting past the type checker? You are returning `data` which is of type `MyClass`, but MyFunction returns `IList<MyClass>`. Does `MyClass` actually implement `IList<MyClass>`?

Comment: @halter73: Thank you a lot! Using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data)` helped me to see that there was a circular dependency that couldn't be converted to json. Why was this exception hidden when I was relying on SignalR?